# directus.io actions - edit collection view template

Tags: directus

I work with directus.io and a collection "customer" and want to add some button in the edit view of a customer, e.g. "Send Email", "Export as XML", ...

How am I able to customize the edit view and what is the best way to do some customize actions?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do this? Would love to know how you went about implementing your specific use case because I need to do something similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this so we can discuss adding to Directus 9.

https://github.com/directus/next/discussions/201

Comment: Hi, the link's broken. I wanted to follow up on the discussion to see what guys came up with because I have a similar use case to the OP's. Thank you.

Comment: To trigger a custom action for a collection/record(s) based on a button click, you would use a Manual Flow:

https://docs.directus.io/app/flows/triggers.html#manual